# Which is better for testing Performance simulator or actual Device

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

My Windows store app loads the background image slowly when I switch from Landscape to portrait mode on the simulator. I believe its happening as the image is little heavy and takes time to load. Is it a good practice to rely on simulator for such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulator is not good for testing performance. You can do initial testing and development on the simulator, but for final testing and especially for performance - you need an actual device or possibly multiple different devices. Trivial apps will work fast on any device, but if you do anything complicated - large images, large collections or otherwise large resources,  complicated animations - especially ones that animate dependent properties and DirectX - these  need to be tested on a range of devices to get good quality.

Comment: I totally agree! From my own experience I can tell you that my application had no issues whatsoever in the emulator when navigating between pages. But using a 512 MB "slow" device showed up rendering times about 2 seconds when navigating between pages ;-)